# How do I make the bot give itself its own role when it joins the server? Like, for example, the mee6 role at mee6

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I noticed that most professional bots get their own role called bot with the joins. now i wonder how this is possible?

Comment: Look on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) Go to your Bot and set the Permissions what you want. And then you have a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to actually do this.

When a server administrator is adding your bot to a server, they need to specify the permissions your bot will receive. Discord will then automatically create this role and assign it to the bot.

On top of that, it's a "managed role", meaning you can't delete it. *I don't even think you can remove it from the bot or even give it to other people.*

Answer (score 2):

Bots get their own role if they get added to the server with any of the Management / Moderator permissions (special permissions) or basic permissions.

Permissions requested in authorization step that will create a role for your bot (basically all of them in the permissions list, link below):

- ADMINISTRATOR
- KICK MEMBERS
- BAN MEMBERS
- MANAGE SERVER
- MANAGE ROLES
- MANAGE CHANNELS
- MANAGE NICKNAMES
- MANAGE WEBHOOKS
- And more...

> https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions

Permissions like *View channel, Send messages..*, basically every "user" permission will also generate a role for the bot, if set in the authorize URL, for example:

> https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=bot_id&permissions=2048&scope=bot

The numbers `2048` (Send messages) you see are "Bitwise permission flags". Using the permission bits in your bot's authorazation URL, indicates that your bot needs "special" permissions in order for it to work properly in a server. Automated roles **cannot be removed or given to other members / bots**, however it is possible to give your bot some other custom made roles specifically made for bots for example.

If a bot gets added to a server with no permissions, it will be treated with user permissions (@everyone) set on the server, thus won't it get a role on it's own.